# Not sure about Bohr's decision to take $f(\tau)=c\tau$ as determining the atom's energy states in his 1913 paper

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

From his 1913 paper, the assumption that the electron's angular momentum in atomic orbits must be a multiple of $\hbar$ is equivalent to saying the energy at each stationary state is $W={\tau h\omega}/2$ ($\omega$ is orbital frequency.) In justifying this, he showed that if instead $W=f(\tau)h\omega$, then we would get radiation frequency $$v=\frac{{\pi}^2me^2E^2}{2h^3}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{f^2(\tau_2)}-\frac{1}{f^2(\tau_1)}\right),$$
where $e, E$ are charges of the electron and the nucleus.

Then it's said that "...in order to get an expression of the same form as Balmer series we must put $f(\tau)=c\tau$." Bohr then went on to use the correspondence principle to justify $c=1/2$.

What I'm not sure I understand is this:

1. Since the Balmer series data only fix the differences $1/{f^2(\tau_2)}-1/{f^2(\tau_1)}$, there should technically be many more choices of $f$ other than a linear function, so, is the claim that it should be linear based on the fact that it just has the simplest form?
2. I understand that Balmer series also give the Rydberg's constant, and that should have constrained $c$ to $1/2$  already. So the fact that he did not say the forced value of $c$ immediately after using the same empirical data is just a matter of presentation style?

Comment: I would say Balmer series pretty much fixes $W$ up to an additive constant. The point was to justify the fact why $W$ had to be quantized, which is what Bohr did

Comment: @lcv Ok, so the answer to both would be yes? Basically, Bohr found an elegant explanation to that, though the data didn’t strictly imply Bohr’s model?

Comment: The answer to i) Is no, there is only a linear $f$ that fits the data

Comment: Is my assumption in (i) correct? Doesn’t 1/f^2(x) is fixed only up to an additive constant?

Comment: Yes you are right. In principle other expressions for $f$ would have worked but they wouldn't have fitted with his model (the expression for $W$ wouldn't match). I guess you are right also about (ii)